# using react-native build android apk

Tags: react-native

i build react-native for android apk has error, need you help!
error info:
C:\Users\Chris.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5934c37098d7fc1d388cdfd621f50e8f\res\values-v24\values-
v24.xml:3:5-157: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Mater
ial.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\Users\Chris.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5934c37098d7fc1d388cdfd621f50e8f\res\values-v24\values-
v24.xml:4:5-135: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Mater
ial.Widget.Button.Colored'.

C:\Users\Chris.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5934c37098d7fc1d388cdfd621f50e8f\res\values-v26\values-
v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.

  > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to ge
  t full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 50s
94 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 92 up-to-date

config info :
...
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.helloworld"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        JPUSH_APPKEY: "01e91c7c174c2c6888228f25",
        APP_CHANNEL : "default"
    ]
```

...

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```